# How to reliably remove Connection figures, whose EditParts are orphans, on removal of respective model object?

Tags: model, refresh, listener, eclipse-emf, eclipse-gef

Assume the following simplified EMF model structure:

```
   Graph
   /   \
Node   Edge
```

In my GEF editor, the `EditPart`s are organized as follows.

**GraphEditPart** (Figure = FreeformLayer) excerpt

```
@Override
protected List<EObject> getModelChildren() {
  List<EObject> childrenList = new ArrayList<EObject>();
  Graph graph = (Graph) getModel();
  childrenList.addAll(graph.getNodes());
  return childrenList;
}
```

**NodeEditPart** (Figure = extending `Figure`) excerpt (*also showing how `Edges` for which a `Node`is source or target are got*)

```
@Override
protected List<Edge> getModelSourceConnections() {
  Node node = (Node) getModel();
  Graph graph = node.getGraph();
  String nodeId = node.getId();
  List<Edge> sourceList = new ArrayList<Edge>();
  if (graph != null)
  sourceList.addAll(graph.getOutEdges(nodeId));
  return sourceList;
}

@Override
protected List<Edge> getModelTargetConnections() {
  // Same principle as getModelSourceConnections
}
```

**Editor class** excerpt (in case it matters)

```
@Override
protected void initializeGraphicalViewer() {
  super.initializeGraphicalViewer();
  GraphicalViewer viewer = getGraphicalViewer();
  viewer.setContents(graph);
  ScalableFreeformRootEditPart root = (ScalableFreeformRootEditPart) viewer.getRootEditPart();
  ConnectionLayer connLayer = (ConnectionLayer) root.getLayer(LayerConstants.CONNECTION_LAYER);
  GraphicalEditPart contentEditPart = (GraphicalEditPart) root.getContents();
  ShortestPathConnectionRouter shortestPathConnectionRouter = new ShortestPathConnectionRouter(contentEditPart.getFigure());
  connLayer.setConnectionRouter(shortestPathConnectionRouter);
}
```

All `EditPart`s have their own adapter (extending `org.eclipse.emf.ecore.util.EContentAdapter` or implementing `org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.Adapter`).

This results in an `EditPart` structure, where `NodeEditPart`s are children of the `GraphEditPart`, and **`EdgeEditPart`s are orphans**, i.e., they have no `parent`. Consequentially, I've had difficulties refreshing figures whenever `Edge`s got added or deleted.

I've managed to make the update work when I *added* an `Edge` by doing an expensive iteration in the `GraphAdapter` (which is notified as a newly created `Edge` must be registered on the `Graph` (`newEdge.setGraph(graph)`):

```
if (notification.getOldValue() == null && notification.getNewValue() instanceof Edge) {     
  for (Object ep : getChildren()) {
    if (ep instanceof NodeEditPart) { // There are in fact other EditParts as well
      Graph graph = (Graph) getModel();
      NodeEditPart nep = (NodeEditPart) ep;
      Node n = (Node) nep.getModel();
    if (graph.getOutEdges(n.getSId()).contains(notification.getNewValue()) || graph.getInEdges(n.getSId()).contains(notification.getNewValue()))
      nep.refresh();
}
```

[**Note:** If - by the way - you can think of any better way of doing this, feel free to hit me up with your solution!]

## Problem

I am unable to reliably remove the `Edge` figure from the editor when deleting the `Edge` model object! Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

I guess the unreliability might have to do with the fact that **(a)** my real life model has three layers of abstraction, and **(b)** that different EMF `Adapter`s don't always recognize changes in the same temporal order (?).

`execute()` from `EdgeDeleteCommand` simply calls `edge.setGraph(null)`, which triggers EMF to clean up after itself (i.e., model elements that aren't connected to the graph are removed from the model).

How can I reliably remove `Edge`s' figures when deleting the respective model object, when the respective `EditPart` is an orphan?

Comment: This (very old!) message describes a similar problem, albeit not with deleting, but with reconnecting connections: http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/gef-dev/msg00198.html. I'm applying the same solution when adding `Edges`, but it doesn't work for deletion.

Comment: Any possibility to take a look at your code?

Comment: @vainolo: Here is a cleaned (well...) and typefied paste of the major classes: http://pastebin.com/GgQUt0dJ. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply let the source and target model objects know that something about them has changed, and let their `Adapter` handle the refresh. Assume the following **`EdgeDeleteCommand`**'s `execute()` method.

```
@Override
public void execute() {
  graph = edge.getGraph();
  source = edge.getSource();
  target = edge.getTarget();

  edge.setGraph(null);
  source.eNotify(new NotificationImpl(Notification.REMOVE, edge, null));
  target.eNotify(new NotificationImpl(Notification.REMOVE, edge, null));
}
```

The last two lines of code notify the source and target model elements that the object `edge` has been removed "from them". This is in fact a *fake* notification message, as `edge` was never a child of `source` or `target`. However, the `Adapter`s attached to the the source and target **`NodeEditPart`** will register this, and can react as follows.

```
@Override
public void notifyChanged(Notification notification) {
  switch (notification.getEventType()) {
  case Notification.REMOVE:
    refresh();
    break;

  default:
    break;
  }
}
```

The `NodeEditPart.refresh()` method will call `getModelSourceConnections()` and `getModelTargetConnections()` "on its way", which will return a list of `Edge`s each, with the deleted `edge` **not** in them anymore.